# SwiftUI some view to its root view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I want to trigger the update of a subview in SwiftUI by changing the state of a @State variable, since it does not update alone when I change the Wallet Object since it is defined as EnvironmentObject. The thing is that I have to initialize the view with environmentObject, and it returns Some View, and cannot cast it to WalletView as it should seem that it should.

```
var walletView =  WalletView().environmentObject(Wallet(cards: reminders))

if walletView = walletView as? WalletView{
    walletView.isPresented = !walletView.isPresented
}
```

How can I access the WalletView object?

I've tried:

```
var walletView =  WalletView()
let someWalletView = walletView.environmentObject(Wallet(cards: reminders))

walletView.isPresented = !walletView.isPresented
```

but the walletView doesn't seem to update. Any clue?

Comment: can you add the ContentView code to be clear, what you want to achieve?

Comment: "I want to trigger the update of a subview ... since it does not update alone when I change the Wallet Object since it is defined as EnvironmentObject." ??? it could be done ... you better to solve it, casting from some View is impossible by definition.

Comment: Thanks, I solved that by changing the variable to @Binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by changing the variable isPresented to @Binding, and modifying it then triggers an update on the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The SwiftUI approach is to change view state *inside* view, so as far as I understood what your going to do with `WalletView` it could be achieved like in the following (scratchy):

```
struct WalletView: View {
   ...
   var body: some View {
      _some_internal_view
         .onAppear { self.isPresented = true }
         .onDisappear { self.isPresented = false }
   }
}
```